# show records from two different models using pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

i have two models ..`video` and `youtube_video`....i have a `index` page to show both videos..so i am **adding** both resultset in one array to show on index page but i am getting pagination error..as `undefined method total pages for array`....what i am doing wrong,,,i know theres a work around as will paginate works on `ActiveRecord Relation` and not on `ActiveRecord`..i even tried model.where...but doesnt works...any workaround on this will be appreciate :)

**my controller..**

```
@videos = Video.includes(:user,:reputations,:tags,:comments).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :per_page => 10).order("created_at DESC")
@youtube_videos=YoutubeVideo.includes(:user,:tags).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :per_page => 10).order("created_at DESC")
@all_videos =@videos + @youtube_videos
```

**my view file**

```
 ###looping on @all_videos....
 <div class="page_info text-center" style="margin-bottom:10px">
<!-- it breaks here -->
  <%= page_entries_info @all_videos %>
 <hr>
<!-- it breaks here  too if i remove above line-->             
<%= ajax_will_paginate @all_videos %>
</div>
```

if i use just `@videos.`.it works but after **merging** with another model..it breaks..any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're paginating each collection, you'll need to add them first then paginate the array.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
@videos = Video.includes(:user,:reputations,:tags,:comments).order("created_at DESC")
@youtube_videos=YoutubeVideo.includes(:user,:tags).order("created_at DESC")
@all_videos = (@videos + @youtube_videos).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

As you're adding two queries together it looks like you'll have to sort the array in ruby.

Comment: Your example isnt good, adding both arrays will not sort them within each other. You are missing a .sort before the call to .paginate

Comment: I just reused his code.  You're right but I was only answering the question about paginating errors.